# ASP MVC OnException send exception data to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm overriding my controllers OnException method.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "ErrorPage",
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

Which gives me my view without any trouble. However, I'd like to be able to send the exception message to the view as well. Something like this:

```
ViewBag.Message = filterContext.Exception.Message;
```

And then in my view:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<h2 class="text-danger">Error message: @ViewBag.Message</h2>
```

I'm probably missing some silly detail, but any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

Turns out I made a blunder. I've changed my overridden method to the one below, and now my ViewBag.Message is sent to the View as well.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ex = filterContext.Exception ?? new Exception("No further information exists.");

        ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
        filterContext.Result = View("ErrorPage");

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

Comment: where have u put `ViewBag.Message = filterContext.Exception.Message` and what trouble exactly do you have? don't u get the exception message in view or something?

Comment: I've updated the OP. Turns out I made a blunder.